# How to correctly reuse the controller with authorization in a Blazor page in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-server-side

Prerequisites:

1. Single ASP.NET Core 3 preview 8 project which includes Blazor server-side and Web Api controllers
2. ASP.NET Core Identity
3. Cookies and JWT token auth schemes for authorization logic in the browser and when calling the API from mobile clients
4. All code samples here have minimum amount of code for brevity.

Here are initial blazor page, model and initial controller

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"
@attribute [Authorize]
@using BlazorApp2.Controllers

<button @onclick="@callController">Call controller</button>

@code {
    private async Task callController()
    {
    }
}
```

```cs
public class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class MessageController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("createMessage")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> CreateMessage(InputModel model)
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        return $"{model.Message} {userId}";
    }
}
```

Utilizing the controller in a "normal" way (by sending http request) gives few built-in benefits: automatic authorization; model validation; populating HttpContext and User properties (and others).

The goal is to reuse the controller when getting data for Blazor page.

**Idea 1**

Configure and inject the controller into Blazor page in such a way that its actions will be called similar to how they are called during http requests. Not sure how to implement this and if this is actually possible. Registering the controller with DI container is not a problem (`AddControllersAsServices()`). But this will not populate controller's `HttpContext` and `User` properties during injection. The only way (which I know) how to get `HttpContext` after controller injection is to configure `IHttpContextAccessor` in `Startup` (`services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`) and inject it into the controller. But this also means that when accessing a controller with http request, the `HttpContext` can be accessed from both injected `IHttpContextAccessor` and controller's `HttpContext` property. Is there any possible problem because of this? This solution will also not give the model validation in the controller. At the same time, model can be validated before sending from Blazor page but I am not sure if I have to re-validate it manually in controller in such a case.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class MessageController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MessageController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    [HttpPost("createMessage")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> CreateMessage(InputModel model)
    {
        var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        return $"{model.Message} {userId}";
    }
}
```

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"
@using BlazorApp2.Controllers
@attribute [Authorize]
@inject MessageController MessageController;

<button @onclick="@callController">Call controller</button>

@code {

    private async Task callController()
    {
        var result = (await MessageController
            .CreateMessage(new InputModel {Message = "Hello"})).Value;
    }
}
```

**Idea 2**

Use HttpClient to make http requests to the controller. 2 problems here. A) Not sure how to register `HttpClient` in DI container in such a way, that all required auth cookies will be added automatically to each call; B) Probably not the ideal solution from the performance point of view because the call will leave the server app (in blazor page) and will go back to the same app (in controller).

What way to go? Is there any other better way? What did I miss in my ideas?

Comment: Hi bro... did you manage to solve this problem? I'm currently facing this exact dillemma.

Comment: This question might be pretty much outdated as a lot of things has changed in Blazor since that time